# How to append text to file in Java 8 using specified Charset

Tags: java, file, logging, java-8, filewriter

I'm looking for an easy and save solution to append text to a existing file in Java 8 using a specified `Charset cs`. The solution which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java) deals with the standard `Charset` which is a no-go in my situation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One way it to use the overloaded version of [`Files.write` that accepts a Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-):

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.APPEND;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.CREATE;

List<String> lines = ...;
Files.write(log, lines, UTF_8, APPEND, CREATE);
```

Comment: Great. I was already thinking about that function but I didn't know that there is an OpenOption "APPEND". I just read "options - options specifying how the file is opened" and thought: No way, this function won't help me.

Comment: Knowing POSIX APIs,  `open()` in this case, helps understanding such things. In the end java can only provide wrappers over system functions. It's also useful to know what you can fall back to via JNA if java isn't powerful enough.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain FYI, it was already answered in the question you linked http://stackoverflow.com/a/29456593/1587046 And then you could just look at the API to see that there is an overloaded version where you can specify the charset https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)

Answer (score 10):

```
Path path = Paths.get("...");
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
List<String> list = Collections.singletonList("...");
Files.write(path, charset, list, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Comment: small typo: StandardOpenOption.APPEND

Answer (score 3):

Based on the accepted answer in the question you pointed at:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt", true), charset)))) {
    out.println("the text");
} catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use append method from Guava [Class Files](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html). Also, you can take a look to [java.nio.charset.Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html?is-external=true).