# Appending to file in utf8

Tags: java, character-encoding, append, bufferedwriter

For a project I need to append to a textfile using UTF-8 encoding.
During my research I found two possibilities:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("file.txt), "UTF-8")
)
```

This will write to my file in UTF-8, but it will overwrite it, rather than append to it if it already exist.

Then I found the code to apend to an existing file with a parameter in the `FileWriter`, but this will not use UTF-8 explicitely, rather than use the default system character set:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true))
```

I now need the possibility to define BOTH the encoding as well as appending to a file. Just rely on the system encoding or change this is not an option.

Any thoughts?

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307382/how-to-append-text-to-file-in-java-8-using-specified-charset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add the `true` paramter to the `FileOutputStream` constructor:

```java
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream("file.txt", true), // true to append
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8                  // Set encoding
    )
);
```

Comment: duh! Apparently I missed the option to set it on the `FileOutputStream`, I only looked at the `FileWriter` option.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("myFile.txt", true), "UTF-8"));
    out.write("Hello World");
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```