# How to set append options and StandardCharsets/Encoding to BufferedWriter in java?

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I am new to java programming and looking for options to write and append file content with java.

Similar options for below C# options.

```
File.WriteAllText(string path, string contents, Encoding encoding);
File.AppendAllText(string path, string contents, Encoding encoding);
```

I though to use BufferedWriter, it have option to pass true/false for FileWriter(String path, boolean append) but i don't have option to provide Encoding.

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path, false);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
    bw.write("appending text into file");
}
```

If I initialize BufferedWriter with Files.newBufferedWriter, I can provide StandardCharsets, but it don't have option to append in case of existing file.

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    bw.write("test");
    bw.append("append test");
}
```

Is it possible to define both option together (Append options and StandardCharsets)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending to file in utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614345/appending-to-file-in-utf8)

Comment: @Olf Although it is similar, this question is about `Files.newBufferedWriter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. if you look into the Files class implementation, there is a method as follows:

```
public static BufferedWriter newBufferedWriter(Path path, Charset cs, OpenOption... options)
```

so you can call a method like

```
BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8, 
                    StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
```

If you use a IDE like Intellij, it would suggest what public methods you are allowed to call.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for same and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [java.nio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) in order to append content to an existing file (if you are using Java 7 or above), maybe you can do something like this:

```
List<String> newContent = getNewContent(...); // Here you get the lines you want to add
Files.write(myFile, newContent, UTF_8, APPEND, CREATE);
```

The imports will need to be done by:

```
java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8, java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.APPEND, java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.CREATE
```

Or you can try using [Guava](https://opensource.google.com/projects/guava):

```
File myFile = new File("/Users/home/dev/log.txt");
String newContent = "This is new content";
Files.append(newContent, myFile, Charsets.UTF_8);
```